# Paperclip attachment_name returns nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I have two models with attached files with using of Paperclip. Those two models are almost identical, however when I call a method '.attachment_name' on each class, for the second model, it returns nil.

I'm posting here code for both models unexpurgated because I don't know what information is important.

Here is the first model:

```
class DocumentationFile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :documentation

  has_attached_file :file, styles: { large: '720x720>', medium: '300x300>', thumb: '100x100>' },
                           default_url: '/images/:style/missing.png'

  validates_attachment :file, content_type: { content_type: [/\Aimage\/.*\Z/,  'application/pdf'] },
                       size: { in: 0.megabytes..5.megabytes }


  validates :file, presence: true
end
```

Here is a second one:

```
class JobExtra < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :job

  has_attached_file :file
  validates_attachment :file, content_type: { content_type: [/\Aimage\/.*\Z/, 'application/pdf'] },
                       size: { in: 0.megabytes..5.megabytes }
end
```

So when in rails console I'm trying to get attachment name for both models with the second model I'm getting nil:

```
2.3.3 :003 > DocumentationFile.attachment_name
 => :file 
2.3.3 :004 > JobExtra.attachment_name
 => nil
```

I can't understand why it's happening and what I'm doing wrong. I've tried to add same validations and options to `has_attached_file` but it didn't help.

So I've run out of ideas and this issue is driving my crazy. I will be grateful for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Can we see your controller? I had the same problem and I solved it by writing in the `create` method:

```
def create
  @job.file = params[:job][:file]
  @job.save
end
```

The reason behind this is that Rails actually processes the file/image, but everything is inside the model. Something like this:

Parameters:

```
{"job"=>{"file"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f
f342035948 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/_2/....jpg>, @original_filename="....jpg", filename=\"....jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">}, "commit"=>"send"}
```